# Add color to certain cells in Excel via pandas - python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, cell

I want to add a highlight specific cells in a `.CSV` file using the `highlight_special` function.

The code runs in the terminal with no exceptions but when I look at the `.CSV` it stays the same

The code takes a csv file runs it to see if there are any words with special characters and then if there are it adds themes to the `siders` list.

The `siders` list is then iterated over in order to highlight cells that contain text that is in the `siders` list.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np 4 LATER
import os

# get the file path
dfile = input("please enter the name of the file you wish ro analyse plus the type(.csv/.xls/.bat): ")
dfile = os.getcwd() + "\\" + dfile
# list of the words with the special letters
siders = []
# special letters list
special_characters = ["\\", ",", "-", "_", "+", ".", "?", "\\", "#", "*", "&", "!", "'", "\""]


# analasys function
def special(data, filter_col):
    # loads the file as a csv
    global datafile
    datafile = pd.read_csv(data)
    # iterates the file line by line plus stating the number of line
    for row, i in datafile.iterrows():
        # tlowercase the column indicated by [filter_col
        lowi = str(i[filter_col]).lower()
        # looks for a special letter in lowi stated..
        for chr in special_characters:
            if chr in lowi:
                siders.append(lowi)  # adds the words with special letters to a side list
                print("succes special character {} found in row {}".format(chr, str(row)))
            else:
                continue
                # print("{} no special chars where found".format(str(row)))
    count = 0
    for index, word in enumerate(siders):
        count += 1
        print(str(index) + " " + word + "\n ")  # prints the special woprds
    print("count of words that need manual review is: {}".format(count))


def highlight_special(cells):  # cells=datafile
    for each in cells:
        if each in siders:
            return ['background_color: yellow']
        else:
            return ['background_color: white']
    datafile.style.apply(highlight_special, axis=1)


def duplicants(datafile):
    pass


highlight_special(dfile)
special(dfile, 'Account Name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `highlight_special()`, `siders` is still empty.
You have to call your method `special()`before.

`highlight_special` also misused (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)), and it is calling itself in the `datafile.style.apply`.

Also, you're using global variables and you are settings them in the function. It won't work unless you are doing something like this (see the [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp)):

```
x = ""
def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()
```

---

here is a working example with of colouring an excel file with `applymap`

```
siders = [1]

df = pd.DataFrame([{'value': 1, "value_2": 913}])
def highlight_cells(value):
    color = "yellow" if value in siders else "white"
    return f"background-color: {color}"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"/tmp/test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df2 = df.style.applymap(highlight_cells)
df2.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```